# add field dbf file error

Tags: python, gdal, dbf

I was adding a column to the DBF file and this error appeared, how can I fix it?

```
import dbf

db = dbf.Table('crop2-fx.dbf')
with db:
    db.add_fields('tipoclasse C(10)')
```

```
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\python.exe" "C:/Users/Secretaria-OBT/Desktop/Estágio Python/23/dbf/addField.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Python/23/dbf/addField.py", line 5, in 
    db.add_fields('tipoclasse C(10)')

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_2.py", line 5015, in add_fields
    old_table = self.create_backup()

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_2.py", line 5240, in create_backup
    bkup = Table(new_name, self.structure(), codepage=self.codepage.name, dbf_type=self._versionabbr, on_disk=on_disk)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_2.py", line 4784, in __init__
    self.add_fields(field_specs)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_2.py", line 5059, in add_fields
    raise FieldSpecError(exc.message + ' (%s:%s)' % (meta.filename, name))

dbf.ver_2.FieldSpecError: Numeric fields must be between 1 and 19 digits, not 24 (C:\Users\SECRET~1\AppData\Local\Temp\crop2-fx_backup.dbf:ampl_b0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of the existing numeric fields is larger than `dbf` currenntly handles (19 digits is the max).  I'm pretty sure the only way past this at the moment is to reduce the numeric field before using `dbf` with it.

Comment: How I can reduce the numeric field? 24 to 19?

Comment: You'll have to do that in the program that created the dbf file.